# Visual studio can't restore packages from Azure Artifcats Feed

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore, azure-artifacts

I have published a library on Azure Artifcats Feed. I can install this `dll` using visual studio NuGet Package Manager manually. But using `NuGet.config`, I can't install the package automatically. The **' Allow NuGet to download missing packages'** is checked. The folder structure of the published library is like this:

```
lib/
  net40/my_libr.dll
  my_lib.dll
```

My `nuget.config` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <!-- remove any machine-wide sources with <clear/> -->
    <clear />
    <!-- add an Azure Artifacts feed -->
    <add key="CCC-FEED" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<org>/_packaging/<feed>/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <!-- also get packages from the NuGet Gallery -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

My project that is trying to use this lib is targeting `net40`. Am I doing anything wrong?

**EDIT1**
My solution has two projects: one is using net35, and the other is using net40. I trying to install the library into the project net40

**EDIT2**
packages are installed and put in the packages folder in the root folder (besides the .sln file). But the dlls are not put in the bin folder.

**EDIT3**
This project was originally created using visual studio 2013

Comment: How's your issue going?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to remove all packages and NuGet.config file, then use `NuGet Package Manager` to install the packages. When you install a package, NuGet records the dependency in either your project file or a `packages.config` file (depending on the project format).

1. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click either **References** or a project and select **Manage NuGet Packages..**

   [image]
2. Make sure you have added the package source (Azure Artifcats Feed) in the NuGet Package Manager settings.

   [image]
3. Select the package and install it.

   [image]

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources